# Jenkins: how to use parameters to skip pipeline parallel steps?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline which runs a bunch of different tests in parallel. Sometimes one of those tests fail, and I want to restart that test only. Before I used pipelines, I used the Matrix Reloaded plugin to achieve this. I want to achieve the same thing with pipelines, and I believe that one way to achieve this is through build parameters.

I have the following pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        booleanParam(name: 'RUBY_LINUX', defaultValue: true, description: 'Ruby unit tests on Linux')
        booleanParam(name: 'RUBY_MACOS', defaultValue: true, description: 'Ruby unit tests on macOS')
    }

    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                parallel(
                    'Ruby unit tests on Linux': {
                        node('linux') {
                            if (params.RUBY_LINUX) {
                                echo 'Ran test.'
                            } else {
                                echo 'Skipped test.'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    'Ruby unit tests on macOS': {
                        node('macos') {
                            if (params.RUBY_MACOS) {
                                echo 'Ran test.'
                            } else {
                                echo 'Skipped test.'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this gives me an error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 24: Expected a step @ line 24, column 13.
               if (params.RUBY_LINUX) {
               ^

WorkflowScript: 41: Expected a step @ line 41, column 13.
               if (params.RUBY_MACOS) {
               ^
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Groovy expressions in the declarative pipeline syntax you can either use the script step or you switch to scripted pipeline.

See the following link for syntax comparison:
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/

The following code fixes you're issue by wrapping the parallel part in a script step:

```
...
stages {
    stage('test') {
        steps {
            script {
                parallel(
                    'Ruby unit tests on Linux': {
                        node('linux') {
                            if (params.RUBY_LINUX) {
                                echo 'Ran test.'
                            } else {
                                echo 'Skipped test.'
                            }
                       }
                     },
                    'Ruby unit tests on macOS': {
                        node('macos') {
                            if (params.RUBY_MACOS) {
                                echo 'Ran test.'
                            } else {
                                echo 'Skipped test.'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```

Comment: You also might want to verify the condintions. I am not sure about declarative pipelines, but with normal pipelines, _all_ parameters are passed as string values, which will make your `if(..)` always true.
You can check this by echoing `params.RUBY_MACOS.class`

Comment: Thanks Philip and Rik, this worked. And apparently the type is java.lang.Boolean.

Comment: +1, but if you're going to use 'script {...', you might as well use the 'if' BEFORE the 'node' and avoid grabbing a node when skipping.